# Windows folder and file created under cygwin git project are not accessible

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

I am using cygwin git to manage my windows source. And I have met the following problems at least twice on different PCs. So I am thinking there is really something tricky behind the weird behavior.

There are two project folder with same source code for comparison. One is managed by cygwin/git, and the other is not. When I try to clean/build the first project. I got a failure complaining the file/folder access fail.

And when I use cygwin to check the folder, it is strange that the user access rights are missing for some new folders created during the build.

```
ICT-EDA@ICT-EDA:/cygdrive/f/stm32/F103_spi_slave/EWARM/F103_spi_slave(master)]$ls -l
total 0
d---rwx---+ 1 ICT-EDA None 0 May 30 11:16 Exe
d---rwx---+ 1 ICT-EDA None 0 May 30 11:16 List
d---rwx---+ 1 ICT-EDA None 0 May 30 11:16 Obj
```

I have check the umask as following

```
ICT-EDA@ICT-EDA:/cygdrive/f/stm32]$umask
0022
ICT-EDA@ICT-EDA:/cygdrive/f/stm32]$ls -l  F103_spi_slave/abc F103_spi_slave/EWARM/abc
ls: cannot access 'F103_spi_slave/abc': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'F103_spi_slave/EWARM/abc': No such file or directory
ICT-EDA@ICT-EDA:/cygdrive/f/stm32]$touch  F103_spi_slave/abc F103_spi_slave/EWARM/abc
ICT-EDA@ICT-EDA:/cygdrive/f/stm32]$ls -l  F103_spi_slave/abc F103_spi_slave/EWARM/abc
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 ICT-EDA None 0 May 30 11:54 F103_spi_slave/abc
----rw----+ 1 ICT-EDA None 0 May 30 11:54 F103_spi_slave/EWARM/abc
ICT-EDA@ICT-EDA:/cygdrive/f/stm32]$ls -ld  F103_spi_slave F103_spi_slave/EWARM
drwxrwx---+ 1 ICT-EDA None 0 May 30 11:54 F103_spi_slave
drwxrwx---+ 1 ICT-EDA None 0 May 30 11:54 F103_spi_slave/EWARM
```

From the above log, you can see with the same umask, the two new created files are with different access rights. I can't see any differences between the two folders, too.
The git is created under F103_spi_slave/.git. So the F103_spi_slave/abc should also be managed by git. It is even confusing. Maybe the problem is windows, not git.

On the other folder, the build finished successfully, as that is not managed by git.

Comment: Try using `noacl` for the disk `F:` https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table. The `Posix` permission used by Cygwin can be hard to manage for NOT Cygwin programs.

Comment: matzeri, thank you. But the problem should be from windows access rights management.   I have no rights to create the folder in Windows explorer even. My computer is Win10 and the file system is NTFS. It seems there is something wrong when I switch branches. And git can't fully restore the properties of some folder. I have some new files on some branches. I have find one way to fix the problem, edit the security page after open the folder property. Update the bad folders same as the normal folder. But the problem will rise again if switches banches.

Comment: What is the Disk "F" ? Do you have read/write access on `/cygdrive/f/stm32` ?

Comment: From cygwin output. Yes, I have the read/write rights. In my last reply, I have the solution for the situation, although not very convinient. Thank you. I am thinking maybe FAT32 should be a better choice for such usage. But I didn't have a disk to try now.